# Play Store support for Android TV on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play-services, android-tv

I use Android Studio and I need an emulator with Play Store support to test the development. However, I could not see the emulator with Play Store support in the Device Manager section in Android Studio.

Do I have to buy a physical Android TV device? Do you have a suggestion for this? Please.

Comment: There is a good guide https://alexilyenko.github.io/androidtv-automated-tests/

Comment: Thank you very much mate, you shared a useful resource. But my question is actually; Is there an AndroidTV emulator with play store support to play improvements in Android Studio? Play store support does not appear on Android TV emulators currently in Android Studio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ADV manager does not show the Play Store icon, but there still is a Play Store on the emulator, it has to be added as an app. At least for Android Q and newer.

[image: No play store icon but still access to it]

[image: Press Add app]

[image: Select Play Store]

Answer (score 8):

When you open Android Virtual Device and click Create Virtual Device, select TV on the side and pick either 1080p or 720p. On the next screen, select Android Q but be sure it's the API level 29 version (not the early "Q" API level). Android Q, API level 29, is currently the only image that has the Play Store installed for Android TV.